# Determining escape sequences for cursor keys canonically

Tags: shell, terminal, arrow-keys, ansi-escape

I'd like to react on cursor keys; for this I want to find out the escape sequences the current terminal is using in a canonical way.  Most solutions just have the strings `"\e[A"` etc. in the source code.  I understand that this is not portable in case the target system uses a different escape sequence.

I tried using `tput` to get the proper escape sequence but `tput kcud1` returns a different escape sequence than what is used for the down arrow key: It returns `"\eOB"` but the key results in `"\e[B"`.  But no capname given to tput results in this string; the best I can manage is tput cud which returns "\e[%p1%dB" from which stripping of all parameters then will finally be the wanted string. But that stripping of parameters also does not sound nice.

What's the canonical way of finding out the proper escape sequence the arrow keys will produce when pressed?  I would be happy about a solution using `tput` or `curses` or even a completely different approach.

Comment: Have a look at ("ncurses", http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/#download_ncurses)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What the cursor keys send depends on the keyboard mode.

`tput` reports their application mode value but by default, the keyboard is in standard mode.

The [DEKCKM](http://www.vt100.net/docs/vt510-rm/DECCKM) command can be used to just change they cursor key behavior, example:

```
printf "\033[?1h"
```

or you can use the `smkx` command which set the keyboard to application mode:

```
tput smkx
```

Reset with:

```
printf "\033[?1l"
```

or

```
tput rmkx
```

Comment: ① I can set the keyboard mode to application mode, then I get the sequences like `"\eOB"` (yes, I checked that).  Is this kind of best practice?  Do programs which run in terminals and which react on the arrow keys do this typically?  And do they typically reset this on exit?  ② Is the `DECCKM` widely present in nowadays terminals?  Can I assume that the reported sequence for the keys is already working and correct is the `DECCKM` isn't present?  ③ Isn't there any way to find out what the sequence in the _cursorkey mode_ is?  What is this switch good for (just one more, it seems to me)?

Comment: ① Yes, that's the common practice with most curses based applications. That's even the reason why it's called application mode in the first place. These applications reset to standard mode when leaving. ② DECCKM should be present in most if not all terminal emulators compatible with the VT100/xterm/ansi and the likes. ③ I don't think there is a standard way, curses abstracts the terminal features but DECCKM is specific / private.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you needed is `tput cud1` (without the `k`). You can also get a list of `tput` commands here:

> http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x405.html

Also you can store those sequences on a variable through `VAR=$(tput xyz)`.

And everything is in `man terminfo`. Online: http://www.manpagez.com/man/5/terminfo/

Comment: Sorry, no.  `tput cud1` delivers for me just a linefeed (0x0a, `"\n"`) and not the wanted `"\e[B"`.  And I understand the documentation so that it should be `kcud1` for the key, so current systems do not seem to be compliant to spec anyway.  The docs you referred to didn't give any more clue on this issue as well (they just state the official, not followed, path).

Comment: `cud` "could" be an escape sequence, but the convention in the terminal database is to store the shortest/fastest sequence of characters to accomplish a given feature.  An ASCII `^J` does that (because curses applications initialize the terminal to allow this behavior, which is different from the default terminal settings).  Its conventional name of "newline" is misleading.