# Escape sequence for arrow keys

Tags: terminal, zsh, putty, tmux, ansi-escape

I am trying to recognize the arrow keys from `stdin` and I have found many resources online suggesting to look for this escape sequence: `ESC-[-D`

However, on my terminal the arrow keys are actually printing the following: `ESC-O-D`

Here is what I get if I run `cat` and press the left arrow:

```
$ cat
^[OD
```

Could you please help me understand why this is happening? Are both escape sequences considered valid?

**Additional information:**

- The `$TERM` environment variable is set to `screen`.
- I am running zsh inside tmux.
- I use Putty to SSH to the server.

Thanks!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determining escape sequences for cursor keys canonically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18658513/determining-escape-sequences-for-cursor-keys-canonically).  Actually those aren't *good* answers, but the point is that the difference is due to cursor *application mode*.

Comment: This is useful! Let me test the command suggested there and I'll get back in the comments

Comment: try to see which bytes they actually send by running `cat | xxd` - on my terminal (Linux Virtual Console), `^[[D` is printed, but the bytes 0x1b, 0x5b 0x44 are sent as expected (ESC + [ + D)